# Detect QR / barcode input onchange event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a working QR scanner working, with scanned QR being decoded into a `textarea` attribute.

However I'm having difficulties detecting the input of this attribute to enable/disable a form button element.

From other stack questions it's noted to be a `paste` type of an event, but `keypress` / `keyup` aren't registering any changes to it.

```
<textarea id="QRinput" class="QRinput"> *QR CODE DECODED* </textarea>
```

And the function for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('.QRinput').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to handle textarea's `change` or `input` event instead of keyup. You can find the difference between them in this [article](https://html.com/attributes/textarea-onchange/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('.QRinput').on('change', function() {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', $(this).val() === '');
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="QRinput" class="QRinput"> *QR CODE DECODED* </textarea>

<input type='submit' value='submit btn'/>
```